# Create HTML links from Powershell search

Tags: powershell

I've created this script to find some files.

```
$wpath = Get-ChildItem F:\@software\ -recurse
$outp = $wpath | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".wav" -and $_.name -like "*hou*"}
$outp = $outp | Select-Object -Property Fullname
$outp | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File f:\@software\htmlout99.html
ii f:\@software\htmlout99.html
```

This gives the results I'm after, in the correct format eg.

```
F:\@software\TFTP-Root\14Hours.wav  
F:\@software\TFTP-Root\ddHours.wav
```

How can I make the results in HTML output clickable links, ie a clickable link to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the brute force method would be to use this:

```
$wpath = Get-ChildItem F:\@software\ -recurse
$outp = $wpath | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".wav" -and $_.name -like "*hou*"}
$outp = $outp | Select-Object -Property @{n='FullName';e={'<a href="file://{0}">{0}</a>' -f $_.FullName}}
$outp | ConvertTo-Html | ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('&quot;','"').Replace('&lt;','<').Replace('&gt;','>') } | Out-File f:\@software\htmlout99.html
ii f:\@software\htmlout99.html
```

It uses a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to translate the FullName into a link.  Then you convert that to HTML.  The problem is that ConvertTo-Html escapes control characters because it assumes the contents are *not* HTML.  I'm sure that if your file names actually have control characters in them that you're bound to have some problems.

The real solution would be to ditch `ConvertTo-Html` altogether and just roll your own.

Comment: Well, brute force or not, that works a treat. Thanks for the very quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the links yourself using ex. calculated properties. `ConvertTo-HTML` will htmlencode some of the characters (like `< and >`), so we need to decode it before saving. Ex:

```
#Load System.Web to get HttpUtility
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$html = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\@software\ -Recurse |
Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".wav" -and $_.name -like "*hou*"} |
Select-Object -Property @{n="Links";e={ "<a href='$(([uri]$_.FullName).AbsoluteUri)'>$($_.FullName)</a>" }} |
ConvertTo-Html -Property "Links"

#Decode special characters like < > etc.
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html) | Set-Content "f:\@software\htmlout99.html"
```

Comment: This is a much better way of doing the same thing I was.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way kind of like @Bacon Bits was mentioning. I use this method often for my sched task notifications.

```
$htmltop = "<html><head></head><body><ul>"
$htmlbottom = "</ul></body></html>"

$wpath = Get-ChildItem F:\@software\ -recurse
$outp = $wpath | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".wav" -and $_.name -like "*hou*"}

$outp = $outp | % { $("<li><a href='file://" + $($_.FullName) + "'>" + $($_.Name) + "</a></li>")}

$htmltop | Out-File F:\@software\htmlout99.html -Append
$outp | Out-File F:\@software\htmlout99.html -Append
$htmlbottom | Out-File F:\@software\htmlout99.html -Append


ii F:\@software\htmlout99.html
```